# How do I su into another user if the user has no password assigned to it?

Tags: permissions, users, su

I have a user named `lap` that was set up during install of a service named `lap`.  I have to be logged in as user `lap` to execute certain functions and to access some directories.  I do not have the root password. I tried:

```
$ su - lap
Password: "MyPassWord"
su: Authentication failure
```

In this case the password I tried is the password of the current user I was logged in as.   Which is the same password I would supply for sudo.  Also i tried:

```
$ sudo su - lap
Sorry, user xxxxxgrp is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - lap' as root on myServerName.
```

In /etc/passwd

```
lap:x:1003:1004::/opt/lap:/bin/csh
```

In /etc/shadow

```
lap:!!:17674:0:99999:7:::
```

Is there a way I can change to user `lap`?

Comment: `sudo -i -u lap`

Answer (score 1):

Only a privileged user (mainly root) can do that or elsewhere can grant you permissions to run things as 'lap' user without password using 'sudo' for specific tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get in as root using `sudo` would be:

`sudo - su`

entering your `sudo` password to log in as root. (By the way, most distros don't assign a default root password on setup).

Once you are in as root, it is as easy as assigning a password to lap by doing:

`passwd lap`

which should allow you to create a new password for that user regardless of what the old one might have been.

However, if you don't have access to an account with `sudo` privileges, you can always boot into the machine in single-user mode. The method of booting in with single-user mode will vary depending on which distribution you are currently running.

This should take you directly to a root shell where you can then change the password for lap as described above, allowing you full access to that account.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the user you are trying to access the 'lap' user from does not have enough privileges to run the `su` command. Other options to change the password via sudo could be `sudo -u lap passwd`

Also other commands can be run as lap using sudo

`sudo -u [user] [command]`

If you are trying to regain access to the user 'root' add the parameter `init=/bin/sh` to the **kernel parameters** at startup

If you are using GRUB

1. press 'e' while in the menu
2. add `init=/bin/sh` (kernel [...]
   init=/bin/sh)
3. `mount / -o remount,rw` to remount filesystem as read-write
4. `passwd` to change the 'root' password
5. `exec /sbin/init` to start system

Once you regain access to the system via 'root' I suggest you check the /etc/sudoers configuration

check if this line is there

`%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL`

this allows all grub wheel users to run all programs I